# xcode running error

Tags: xcode

I am making an iphone app in xcode and I changed a few things and i got this error:

```
2012-01-01 10:55:40.295 Dodge Cars free[549:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x68912d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key RoadImage.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13cd052 0x155ed0a 0x13ccf11 0x9c4032 0x935f7b 0x935eeb 0x950d60 0x24391a 0x13cee1a 0x1338821 0x24246e 0x244010 0x2414a 0x24461 0x237c0 0x32743 0x331f8 0x26aa9 0x12b7fa9 0x13a11c5 0x1306022 0x130490a 0x1303db4 0x1303ccb 0x232a7 0x24a9b 0x1fc8 0x1f25 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

I don't know exactly what it means but the RoadImage it is referring to is a UIImageView in my .xib file. I have tried to clean the application but that doesn't seem to help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem in the xcode project information I didn't realize but I changed my main interface to my .xib file and for whatever reason that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe in your .h file you changed:

```
IBOutlet UIImage * RoadImage;
```

to something that fits with the naming convention:

```
IBOutlet UIImage * roadImage;
```

but in your xib you are still trying to connect to RoadImage, go look at your connection, I would guess that you have something connected that isn't valid anymore.

Comment: As far as i can tell that is all fine, what I found out is that if I delete that UIImageView it gives me the same error but with another UI element that is in my .xib file.

Comment: well you are trying to set something that isn't declared, do you get any warnings?